# How to install tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I installed **cuda-11.0** and **cuDNN-8.2** and **Tensor-RT 7.1**. And then installed **tensorflow-gpu**. But `tf.is_gpu_available()` is showing **False**.
Actually, I installed **tensorflow-gpu** first. I have **pip3 20.1.1** and **Nvidia GForce 930MX** and **Ubuntu 20.04**.

Here is the `nvidia-smi` command output:
[image]

Comment: You should provide more details, at least: operating system (linux/mac/windows), hardware (GPUs), method of installation (pip/conda)

Comment: I added... @ncasas

Comment: Can you include the output of command `nvidia-smi`?

Comment: I did.. @ncasas

Answer (score 1):

Right now Tensorflow 2.1 doesn't support **CUDA 11.0**. Downgrade CUDA to version 10.1 and try again.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: Having to downgrade is not acceptable. This sucks.

Answer (score 0):

for macosx/linux tensorflow gpu installation - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpUvdLD932c&list=PLjy4p-07OYzulelvJ5KVaT2pDlxivl_BN&index=8.
for windows 10 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrkEYf-YDyI&list=PLjy4p-07OYzulelvJ5KVaT2pDlxivl_BN&index=9

Answer (score 0):

**Tensorflow** could not found gpu because, the **Cuda Toolkit** version was 11. But, **cuDNN** version was 8.2RC + cuda 11. But in **Tensorflow-2.2.0** it will work when cuda toolkit and cudnn both has cuda of version 10.1. Cuda 11.0 is not supported.